# How to delete and rename files in C on windows

Tags: c, file-io

I am working on program which renames or deletes the files in the file system. I am using C and it works well on linux machine but fails on windows. i use gcc compiler suit. and following is the code it does not delete the files from my file system.

Thanks in advance

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("Program demonstrating file renaming and file deletion. \n");

 printf("Enter file name to be deleted : ");
 char fdelete[25];

 fflush(stdin);

 gets(fdelete);

 printf("Enter file name to be renamed : ");
 char frename[25];

 fflush(stdin);

 gets(frename);

 if (remove(fdelete)!=0)
 { 
  printf("error deleting the file.\n");
 }

 if(rename("test2.txt",frename)!=0)   //test2.txt is the original file
 {
  printf("eeror renaming the file.\n");
 }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel an embarrassing urge to exploit the buffer overflow vulnerability in your program to gain root access to your computer. In other words, `gets(fdelete);` -> `fgets(fdelete, sizeof(fdelete), stdin);`. Also, don't name your variable `fdelete`. It looks like a theoretical C stdlib function deleting a `FILE *`. Name it `buf` (a buffer, which it is).

Comment: have you tried looking at `errno` to see what the error code for the failed operations is? all fine and dandy to say there was a problem, but it's pretty useless when you could SAY what the problem is, e.g. `error deleting file: $errno`-type stuff.

Comment: Best practice for renaming files probably depends on your target operating system. Might want to add that to the tags.

Comment: Doesn't Windows provide a lot of posix functions with an underscore prefix?  Maybe `_rename()` and `_remove()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of problems.

```
char fdelete[25];
```

This might have been at least close to acceptable 20 years ago, but nowadays the chances of a file name over 25 characters long are pretty high. You probably want to use `FILENAME_MAX`.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

This (calling `fflush` with a file opened for input as its argument) gives undefined behavior. Just don't do it.

```
gets(fdelete);
```

`gets` is a serious source of security problems. Never use it. Use `fgets` instead.

```
char frename[25];
```

Same problem as with `fdelete`.

```
fflush(stdin);
gets(frename);
```

Same problems as above.

All that said, `remove` should delete a file provided there are no other links to that file and the name you pass to it is the name of an actual file.